# Comma usage while explaining a single word

Tags: punctuation, commas

Consider the following sentence:

```
The French word entrailles means inward.
```

Is it advisable to surround entrailles with commas in this case like this?

```
The French word, entrailles, means inward.
```

Or would it be better to just use one comma like this?

```
The French word, entrailles means inward.
```

Or is it better without any? Please advise from the American English standpoint should there be any US-UK variation in style.

Comment: Use quotes: *the French word "entrailles" means inward*. If you have more advanced typographic options available to you, e.g. as we do on this StackExchange site, you could use italics instead of quotes: *entrailles*.

Comment: I know I can use quotes, italics, bold, etc. But my question is regarding the appropriateness commas in this context. I want to know what style guides dictate when it comes to commas in this kind of situation.

Comment: Style guides dictate using quotes (Google "use-mention distinction"). If you can't use quotes, you must set apart the word some other way; italics would be ideal. But if you *can't* use quotes, or italics, or any other typographic trick, you must do something, and I suppose commas, though not anyone's first choice, could be used in a pinch.

Comment: Don't use commas unless you can't use quotes or italics.

Comment: Is it absolutely incorrect if I don't use any of those as in the first example?

Comment: @Amit: If you're in a context where you really ***can't** use quotes or italics*, I don't think notions of "correct/incorrect" are relevant.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia I don't think commas are appropriate at all here. Unless you have already said the word "entrailles" in the sentence right before it and you are explaining the meaning now (and it's the only French word used), then use quotes or italics, as said in the above comments.

Comment: Since probably every person here understands the sentence with no commas, I would hesitate to call it absolutely wrong. Just like I can refer to the English word inward without using commas, quotation marks, bold, or italics.

Comment: @CarSmack, in that example you just gave I actually missed the word "inward" and so I was confused to when I got to the end of the sentence, and so had to go back and re-read it more carefully to find the source of my confusion (in other words, because "inward" wasn't set apart, I missed it).

Answer (score 1):

Commas usually depict a small pause while reading. This is a mark of clarity while saying something.
In your case, 
'The French word entrailles means inward.' 
      - this sentence is the most precise. You do not need to place entrailles between commas as it is evident that you are explaining the meaning of that particular word. As Dan Bron suggested in his answer above, you can use double quotes to lay emphasis on that word.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is grammatically correct.

The other two examples are borderline incorrect and certainly less understandable.

The first is clearly the best.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping to get but before I accept it, I have to ask you if you have any reference to any style guide or something with a similar authority backing up your answer.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia Good luck finding an "authoritative" source, such as a style guide, providing **nonstandard** usages. It has been stated already that *italics* are the way to go. Since a typewriter doses not have italics, underlining the word is the way to go there. The comments to use quotation marks are not backed up by a source. But again, to ask for Style Guides to provide nonstandard usage is a little misguided, if you ask me.